# Ngx-chips populate <tag-input> not showing `name` or `id` which provided dynamically

Tags: html, angular, typescript, autocomplete, ngx-chips

I am working with `ngx-chips` and below code is to populate suggestion `tag-input` field.

```
<div *ngFor="let field of fields; let i=index">
    <label class="pt-3 font-600">{{field.label}} {{field.id}}</label>
    <tag-input
      [identifyBy]="'id'"
      [inputClass]="riProSuggestionField"
      [displayBy]="'name'"
      (onFocus)="onFocusInput($event)"
      [placeholder]="field.placeholder"
      [(ngModel)]="field.data"
      [inputId]="field.id"
      [onlyFromAutocomplete]="true"
      name="{{field.label}}"
    >
      <tag-input-dropdown
      [autocompleteObservable]="getSuggestions"

      </tag-input-dropdown>
    </tag-input>
  </div>
```

In above code I have multiple fields and I am populating it by doing `ngFor` , While doing this I am trying different name to each tag-input as I have to fetch different fields data to each individual input tag. Having only one `autoCompleteObservable` function called `getSuggestions` which will work accordingly to which field have focused right now.

My `.ts` code is to get Which input have clicked is

```
onFocusInput(data) {
    const focusedElement = document.getElementsByClassName('ng2-tag-input--focused');
    console.log('Focused element', focusedElement);
  }
```

I wanted to get the name of focused `<tag-input></tag-input>` so that I could `getSuggestions` according to this name.